# Nested Wordpress Shortcodes of Different Types

Tags: shortcode

How would you do a shortcode wrapper that can differentiate between different nested shortcodes.

```
[teaching_tool_wrapper param1="true" param2="false"]
    [chord param1="something"]
    [scale param1="something-else"]
[/teaching_tool_wrapper]
```

I have it working fine with just the [chord] shortcode, however i'm not sure how to get the wrapper differentiating between the two different types of nested shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Can be useful `do_shortcode` function?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution.  do_shortcode will do all the shortcode contents in the wrapper, however I wanted the nested shotcodes processed in different places.

```
<?php 
    // make sure only the [chord] shortcodes are inserted here.
    $custom_chords = rtrim($custom_chords, "]");
    $custom_chords_array = explode(']', strip_tags($custom_chords));
    foreach($custom_chords_array as $custom_chord){
        if(strpos($custom_chord, '[chord') != false){
            echo do_shortcode($custom_chord .']');
        }
    }
?>
```

Seems to work!